# Raspberry Pi to autorun a script that save file to USB and close down at specific time

Tags: usb-flash-drive, raspberry-pi, cron, autosave

I have a script that, at a specific time like 2.55pm on a Friday, saves on open spreadsheet file to a USB and shuts down.  The Files name is attend.ods and it is in the Documents folder on a Raspberry Pi 3.

How to autorun that script?

Comment: Cool. So what's your question?

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: The script needs to autorun.

Comment: So it's not really "I want a script!" but "How do I make a script run at a specific time?". Which is good, because the former isn't on-topic. It's not even a question. You should edit your question. And since your already have the cron tag, you should perhaps expand on what's keeping you from using it.

Answer (score 1):

Run `crontab -e`
At the end of the file, put

```
55 14 * * fri /path/to/script.sh
```

for more information, run `man 5 crontab`